# Which questions led to the creation of a new package?

Tags: discussion, big-list

TeX.sx occasionally inspires people to be ingeniously creative and write cool packages. Let's have a list of all the CTAN packages that originated in a question on TeX.sx.

I suggest a single CW answer for starters, listing the packages alphabetically, following this pattern:

1. [`babyloniannum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum) by [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (Raphink). Origin: [Typesetting Babylonian numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25939/typesetting-babylonian-numerals)

```
0. [`packagename`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/packagename) by
[package creator's name](link to their profile) (package creator's user name, if ≠ package
creator's name). Origin: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/number/question
```

(template in the answer source, the numbering works automagically)

If the list ever becomes cluttered, we can consider introducing categories.

---

This question is the realization of a suggestion to [Mark questions that led to creating a new package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/mark-questions-that-led-to-creating-a-new-package/1713#1713).

If you notice a package-triggering question that hasn't been marked with [the box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/mark-questions-that-led-to-creating-a-new-package/1704#1704) yet, please add it.

A non-restricted overview of package maintainers on TeX.sx can be found at [Who are the package maintainers here?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here).

Comment: Can we link to posts on the TeX-SX blog as well?

Comment: @Andrew: Sure, why not. This question is intended as a pool of information, so such links will be helpful, as long as the post doesn't get cluttered.

Comment: Should this include questions whose answers got included in existing packages? If so, how should we mark the questions?

Comment: @Raphink: If it's just a bug fix or something similarly minor, I'd say no; if it's a new feature for a package, it might be interesting. I'm not sure though if we should put it in this question. Are there many posts that this would apply to? Could you give us one or a few examples?

Comment: @doncherry: I'm building the `impnattypo` from the answers of quite a few questions.

Comment: @doncherry: I went with "This question led to a new feature in a package": [Ensure minimal length of last line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28357) . Feel free to suggest a nicer wording while it's hardly used.

Comment: Should there be a tag `[new-package]` for these threads? It would make them easily trackable.

Comment: @tohecz: We actually decided against this option, see [Mark questions that led to creating a new package](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1702)

Comment: May be "inspired by a question on TEX.SE" for example [download](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/download) might also have a separate section here in the list.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. [`abraces`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abraces) by [Werner Grundlingh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) (Werner). Origin: [Asymmetric overbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/asymmetric-overbrace)
2. [`aobs-tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) by [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino). Origin:
   [Highlighting in Beamer using TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes)
3. [`autonum`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum) by
   [Patrick Häcker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7323/mmm) (MMM). Origin: [showonlyrefs and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55206/showonlyrefs-and-cleveref)
4. [`babyloniannum`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum) by [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Typesetting Babylonian numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25939/typesetting-babylonian-numerals)
5. [`bib2gls`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) by
   [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot). Origin: [Is there a program for managing glossary tags?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342544/question)
6. [`biblatex-nejm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm) by
   [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel). Origin: [Biblatex style file for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26891/biblatex-style-file-for-new-england-journal-of-medicine-nejm)
7. [`biblatex-trad`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad) by
   [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel). Origin: [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo)
8. [`bibleref-mouth`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibleref-mouth) by
   [Chad Parry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9466/chad-parry). Origin: [Can a fragile command's output ever be a hyperref address?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35720/can-a-fragile-commands-output-ever-be-a-hyperref-address)
9. [`bohr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bohr) by [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/) (cgnieder). Origin: [Draw Bohr atomic model with electron shells in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73410/draw-bohr-atomic-model-with-electron-shells-in-tex)
10. [`braids`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/braids) by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey). Origin: [How to make nice braids diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-make-efficiently-nice-braids-diagrams). Blog: [The Braids Package](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-braids-package/)
11. [`casiofont`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/casiofont) by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn). Origin: [Easiest way to create TeX macro/code to access symbols from particular font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434335/2693)
12. [`checkcites`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites) by
    [Enrico Gregorio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427) (egreg) and [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094). Origin: [Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries were not used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43276)
13. [`chkfloat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chkfloat) by [Tomáš Hejda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002) (yo'). Origin: [How can I find out what pages my floats are on (without looking at every page of the document)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67833)
14. [`circledsteps`](https://ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps) by [Romano Giannetti](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano) (Rmano) . Origin: [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)
15. [`clrstrip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clrstrip) by [Jonathan P. Spratte](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) (Skillmon). Origin: [Insert pictures inside a color box spanning the whole page width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434520/)
16. [`comment_io`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment_io) by [Carl Martin Henrik Larsson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3555/speldosa) (Speldosa). Origin: [Create an enumerate environment that can be turned off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241780/create-an-enumerate-environment-that-can-be-turned-off)
17. [`concepts`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/concepts) by
    [Michiel Hel­ven­steijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886/mhelvens) (mhelvens). Origin: [What should I build my new nomenclature package on top of?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78155/what-should-i-build-my-new-nomenclature-package-on-top-of)
18. [`conteq`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/conteq) by
    [Joachim Breitner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15107/joachim-breitner). Origin: [Automatic arrangement of equations with comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108277/automatic-arrangement-of-equations-with-comments)
19. [`coseoul`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/coseoul) by
    [Michael Teubner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7279/tom-bombadil) (Tom Bombadil). Origin: [Create context sensitive headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings/)
20. [`ctanupload`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctanupload) by [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). Origin: [CLI tool to upload to CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27244/cli-tool-to-upload-to-ctan)
21. [`duckuments`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/duckuments) by
    [Jonathan P. Spratte](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) (Skillmon). Origin: [Getting ducks in example images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419751/getting-ducks-in-example-images)
22. [`embrac`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac) by
    [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) (cgnieder). Origin: [Upright parentheses in italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/upright-parentheses-in-italic-text)
23. [`etoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) by [jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu). Origin: [Can I get a list of all sections as a simple enumerate-list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79682/can-i-get-a-list-of-all-sections-as-a-simple-enumerate-list)
24. [`fancytabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs) by
    [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Exact position of a node in a rectangle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/exact-position-of-a-node-in-a-rectangle)
25. [`feynmp-auto`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto) by
    [Enrico Gregorio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) (egreg). Origin: [Configuring Texmaker to run mpost for FeynMP Graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74244/configuring-texmaker-to-run-mpost-for-feynmp-graphics)
26. [`fnpct`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) by
    [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) (cgnieder). Origin: [Is there a way to automatically change kerning between commas/full stops and footnote marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-kerning-between-commas-full-stops-and-foo)
27. [`fontbook`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontbook) by
    [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Generate font collection book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22272/generate-font-collection-book)
28. [`footnotebackref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref) by
    [Holger Lange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10570/holle) (Holle). Origin: [Footnote backreference with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/footnote-backreference-with-hyperref)
29. [`footnoterange`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnoterange) by
    [Hans-Martin Münch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen) (Stephen). Origin: [Compressing consecutive footnote marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44165/compressing-consecutive-footnote-marks)
30. [`fullwidth`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) by
    [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel). Origin: [How to switch between two margin sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes)
31. [`halloweenmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath) by
    [he prefers to remain nameless](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69818/gum) (GuM). Origin: [Seasonal Challenge (Contributions from TeXing Dead Welcome)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336768/seasonal-challenge-contributions-from-texing-dead-welcome/338377#338377)
32. [`hardwrap`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hardwrap) by
    [Kevin Godby](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80/godbyk) (godbyk) and [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson). Origin: [How can I word-wrap LaTeX warning/error output?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/how-can-i-word-wrap-latex-warning-error-output)
33. [`he-she`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/he-she) by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn). Origin: [Alternate he / she in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10787/2693)
34. [`hf-tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) by [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino). Origin:
    [Beamer: highlighting aligned math with overlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52598/beamer-highlighting-aligned-math-with-overlay)
35. [`hobby`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) by [Andrew Stacey](http://tex.stackexchance.com/users/86).  Origin: [Curve through a sequence of points with Metapost and TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54771/86)
36. [`impnattypo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) by
    [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [French typography recommendations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/french-typography-recommendations)
37. [`intopdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/intopdf) by [Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%C3%BCger). Origin: [Embed non-PDF files (e.g., BibTex) into PDF with hyperlink in the PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418606/embed-non-pdf-files-e-g-bibtex-into-pdf-with-hyperlink-in-the-pdf/418827#418827)
38. [`lstautogobble`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) (`lstaddons` bundle) by
    [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer).
    Origin: [How to automatically skip leading white spaces in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19953/2975)
39. [`lstlinebgrd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) (`lstaddons` bundle) by
    [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer).
    Origin: [Creating a zebra effect using listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18969/2975)
40. [`lua-check-hyphen`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-check-hyphen) by
    [Patrick Gundlach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/) (topskip). Origin: [Reviewing hyphenations with LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60435/reviewing-hyphenations-with-luatex)
41. [`lua-ul`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul) by
    [Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%C3%BCger). Origin: [Underline part of a word while preserving kerning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446444/)
42. [`lua-visual-debug`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) by
    [Patrick Gundlach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/) (topskip). Origin: [How can I visualize boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2083)
43. [`macros2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e) by
    [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). Origin: [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands)
44. [`matlab-prettifier`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) by [Julien Cretel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs) (Jubobs). Origin: [What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document)
45. [`moderntimeline`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline) by [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Putting a timeline for dates in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/putting-a-timeline-for-dates-in-moderncv)
46. [`modiagram`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/modiagram) by
    [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) (cgnieder). Origin: [Molecular orbital diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13863/molecular-orbital-diagrams-in-latex)
47. [`movement-arrows`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/movement-arrows) by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn). Origin [Movement arrows in gloss](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140142/2693)
48. [`mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) by
    [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). Origin: about 80% of all questions
49. [`newenviron`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newenviron) by [Ahmed Musa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/994/ahmed-musa). Origin: [What is the problem with nested environments using \BODY (environ package)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101629/what-is-the-problem-with-nested-environments-using-body-environ-package)
50. [`nowidow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nowidow) by [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Expansion issue with \begingroup and \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26272/expansion-issue-with-begingroup-and-foreach)
51. [`ocgx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) by
    [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit). Origin: [How to make a diagram composed of superimposed layers where the viewer can make each layer visible or invisible independently of the other layers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65096/14500)
52. [`odsfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/odsfile) by
    [Michal Hoftich](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21) (michal.h21). Origin: [Insert libreoffice table as input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60378/insert-libreoffice-table-as-input)
53. [`parnotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes) by [Chelsea Hughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9092/chel) (Chel). Origin: [Placing footnotes or endnotes at the end of the current paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34746/placing-footnotes-or-endnotes-at-the-end-of-the-current-paragraph)
54. [`pgf-blur`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-blur) by [Martin Giese](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13195/mabartibin) (mabartibin). Origin: [Reuse of soft path in fading declaration? Transformation of fadings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50422/reuse-of-soft-path-in-fading-declaration-transformation-of-fadings)
55. [`pgfkeyx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeyx) by
    [Ahmed Musa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/994/ahmed-musa). Origin: [Can pgfkeys deal with active comma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51336/can-pgfkeys-deal-with-active-comma/)
56. [`qrcode`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode) by
    [Anders Hendrickson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/85836/anders-hendrickson). Origin: [pgf-Tikz QR code generator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/pgf-tikz-qr-code-generator)
57. [`recorder-fingering`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/recorder-fingering) by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn). Origin: [Chart for Recorder fingering notation in Musixtex with Tikz and Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674847)
58. [`romanbar`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/romanbar) by
    [Hans-Martin Münch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen) (Stephen). Origin: [Roman numerals with over- and underline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/roman-numerals-with-over-and-underline)
59. [`sankey`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sankey) by [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit). Origin: [How to draw a Sankey Diagram using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40159/14500)
60. [`sclang-prettifier`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sclang-prettifier) by [Julien Cretel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs) (Jubobs). Origin: [How can I automatically highlight SuperCollider symbols and environment variables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159245/how-can-i-automatically-highlight-supercollider-symbols-and-environment-variable)
61. [`screenplay-pkg`](https://www.ctan.org/pgk/screenplay-pkg) by [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) Origin: [converting documentclasses into environments: is it possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26227/2693)
62. [`scrjrnl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrjrnl) by
    [Raphaël Pinson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (ℝaphink). Origin: [Making a daily devotional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/making-a-daily-devotional)
63. [`shadowtext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shadowtext) by
    [Yori Zwols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13939/yori) (Yori). Origin:
    [How to create text with shadows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53369/how-to-create-text-with-shadows)
64. [`smartdiagram`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram)
    by [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino). Origin: [PowerPoint's "Smart Art" for TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78310/powerpoints-smart-art-for-tikz)
65. [`spath3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3) by
    [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey). Origins: ['Poster' fountain pen nib style text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16899) and [Knot diagrams in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32125)
66. [`tagging`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging) by
    [Brent Longborough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/344/brent-longborough) (Brent.Longborough). Origin: [Document configuration via tags or labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/document-configuration-via-tags-or-labels)
67. [`tikzducks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks) by [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter). Origin: [How can we draw a duck (in order to create a tikzducks package and store it in CTAN)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/how-can-we-draw-a-duck-in-order-to-create-a-tikzducks-package-and-store-it-in-c)
68. [`tikz-feynman`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) by
    [Joshua Ellis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26980/jp-ellis) (JP-Ellis). Origin: [Package for typesetting Feynman diagrams (efficiency of `feynmp` and `tikz`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz)
69. [`tikzscale`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) by
    [Patrick Häcker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7323/mmm) (MMM). Origin: [pgfplots: how can I scale to text width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/pgfplots-how-can-i-scale-to-text-width)
70. [`tkz-kiviat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat) by
    [Alain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes). Origin: [How to draw Kiviat Diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10060/how-to-draw-kiviat-diagrams)
71. [`tqft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) by
    [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey). Origin: [Topological Quantum Field Theory diagrams with pstricks or tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/topological-quantum-field-theory-diagrams-with-pstricks-or-tikz). Blog: [The TQFT Package](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/the-tqft-package/)
72. [`typewriter`](https://ctan.org/pkg/typewriter) by
    [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle). Origin: [Use LaTeX to simulate old typewriter written texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts)
73. [`underoverlap`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/underoverlap) by
    [Michiel Hel­ven­steijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886/mhelvens) (mhelvens). Origin: [(How) can I manually specify the axis of a (horizontal) box in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/how-can-i-manually-specify-the-axis-of-a-horizontal-box-in-math-mode), [How to fix the math-spacing when a lot of \phantom, \mathrlap, etc. are used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95897/how-to-fix-the-math-spacing-when-a-lot-of-phantom-mathrlap-etc-are-used)
74. [`unravel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unravel) by
    [Bruno Le Floch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2707/bruno-le-floch). Origin: [A LaTeX log analyzer application (visualizing TeX expansion)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/a-latex-log-analyzer-application-visualizing-tex-expansion/124880#124880)
75. [`xcite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcite) by
    [Enrico Gregorio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) (egreg). Origin: [Use bibliography numbers and citation from other file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/use-bibliography-numbers-and-citation-from-other-file)
76. [`xpatch`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) by
    [Enrico Gregorio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) (egreg). Origin: [How can I use \patchcmd with commands with optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/how-can-i-use-patchcmd-with-commands-with-optional-arguments) (now also [`regexpatch`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) that will be merged with `xpatch` in the future)
77. [`xpeek`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpeek) by
    [Joel C. Salomon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2966/j-c-salomon). Origin: [Peek ahead for next token not in token-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63971/peek-ahead-for-next-token-not-in-token-list)
78. [`xurl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) by Herbert Voß (account removed, now [user2478](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/)). Origin [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/)

Thanks to all of them for sharing their work with the rest of the world!