# Should a tag of package-request be created?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Over the past ten years, I asked a lot of questions and received a lot beautiful customized answers.

If I found that the answer I got is very useful and should be highlighted in a package for future users, could I post a question asking for converting a specific answer into a package?

If it is acceptable, then should a tag be created for this purpose or not?

Comment: A question about the *mechanics* of creating a package (what would I have to do to turn this code into a package) would be very much on topic here. Such a question would probably not be answered by actually making the code into a package and uploading it to CTAN, but by explaining what would have to be done to do so. (We already have the tag `package-writing` to cover that, I'd say.) ...

Comment: ... A question of the form: 'Who can make this code into a package for me and release it on CTAN?' presumably only has one acceptable answer ('yes, I have done that, here is the link'), but comes with much more additional responsibilities than a normal question on TeX.SX (turning the code into a package is probably the easy bit, but you'd also want to write documentation and may ultimately be expected to maintain the package, ...). This goes beyond what an answer on this site usually implies.

Comment: @moewe I understand. Well explained point!

Comment: Also, turning an answer into a package is often more work than just putting the code into a `.sty` (plus the things others have already mentioned). I'd want that package to be easier customizable than an answer on TeX.SX, so I'd have to add options and generalise the code, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess asking to create a package in a question would "need more focus", i.e., is too broad for the site. Converting an answer to a specific question into a generally applicable package is likely to be a lot of work, in providing sensible user commands, testing, writing documentation, and further maintainance.

Alternatively it could be argued that such a question is focused - writing a package is a lot of work but answering a question about writing a package can be quick (yes or no, possibly with some arguments in case of 'no'). However, in this case it is likely to be opinion-based, because the answer is "this is/is not a good idea because X". Also the voting on such a question would be problematic, it could be interpreted as a meta-style "upvote=support the request, downvote=disagree with the request", which means you could loose reputation not because the question is bad but because people disagree with you that a package should be created. Asking such a question on Meta itself is also not a good fit because Meta questions should be about the site only.

Both of the above arguments are reason for closure of such a question. Creating a tag therefore does not seem to be a good idea.

You could leave a comment under the answer to suggest the idea to the answerer. If they are interested then such a comment will be sufficient to initiate the process. Converting answers into packages has happened 73 times to date, see [Which questions led to the creation of a new package?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-questions-led-to-the-creation-of-a-new-package).