# Question that led to a new program

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is a way of marking [questions that led to a new package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1704/3555). However, recently one of my own questions [inspired me to create a program](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244115/3555) (written in Python) to help me manipulate tex-files. Is this something that we want to have a way of marking as well, or are these type of events too infrequent/not relevant?

Comment: [`latexindent`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) falls under this scope.

Comment: `checkcites` was born from a question here as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/unused-bibliography-entries-how-to-check-which-entries-were-not-used `:)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would consider this as a part of [Mark questions that led to creating a new package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/mark-questions-that-led-to-creating-a-new-package/1704#1704).

The reason lies in the confusion by the word *package* -- on one hand, it means "a thing that has something to do with `\usepackage`", on the other hand, it means "whatever is a package on CTAN or elsewhere". Your new Python program IMHO falls into the 2nd definition of a package.

It shall as well be listed in [Which questions led to the creation of a new package?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-questions-led-to-the-creation-of-a-new-package?rq=1).

Comment: I see. Yeah, I obviously got confused by the term "package" as well. Is it prefered that packages (when they really are independent programs) are uploaded to CTAN instead of for example Github? I would guess that the answer is "yes", and I'll put it there as well.

Comment: i think including it among the "new package" questions is reasonable.  but if that idea is accepted, the text of that question needs to be extended, and ideally some convention defined for identifying "program" as opposed to `\usepackage` package is needed.